# Probability of same order

Tags: probability

I'm a bit confused how to approach these type of questions. I can manage to calculate the some but the others are challenging for me.

We have 2 bags, each contains 10 numbers (0,1,2,...,9). We're expected to pick 6 numbers and the outcome is {1,2,3,4,5,6}. By the way there is no replacement.

$1)$ Probability of getting same numbers: $\frac{6!.4!}{10!}$

$2)$ Probability of getting same numbers and same order: $\frac{4!}{10!}$

$3)$ For a total of $100$ draws, what is the probability that in these draws two consecutive draws have the same numbers?

$4)$ For a total of $100$ draws, what is the probability that same $6$ numbers appear at least twice in any of these draws?

I can do the first and the second question but I don't know how to approach the third and fourth? If my calculations are right then how can I implement these results to third and fourth?

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: For (3) and (4), try to find the probability of the opposite event.  For (3), no two consecutive draws being the same numbers... there are $\binom{10}{6}$ different equally likely selections of numbers.  Given a particular selection of numbers for one step, there are how many ways to choose the numbers for the next step such that it isn't the same set of numbers?  What is the chance of this happening?  For this to happen that the first and second sets are different *and* the second and third sets are different... what do we do here?  Add?  Multiply?

Comment: For (4), the same advice... except note here we check that the second is different than first, the third is different than second *and first*, the fourth is different than third *and second and first* etc...

Comment: Oh i see, thanks a lot!